# How to add background image to a table header th cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-image

I have a table in html and I want to add different background images to each `<th>` of the table, but the background image is not coming up

I tried by adding in following way

```
<tr>
  <th>Test table header</th>
  <th style="background: url("external url");" >Column 1 header <br/>How to</th>
  <th style="background: url("external url");" >Column 2 header <br/>How to</th>
</tr>
```

But the image is not coming up.
Tried below alternative as well

```
<th style="background-image: url("external url");" >Column 1 header <br/>How to</th>
```

Comment: It's just a syntax error. Replace _style="background: url("external url");"_ with _style="background: url('external url');"_  The use of double quotes inside double quotes is causing the code to fail.

Comment: A good editor will make this kind of mistake apparent.

Answer (score 1):

It should work using ' instead of "

```html
<th style='background: url("external url");' >Column 2 header <br/>How to</th>
```

Column 2 header 
How to

Comment: I have tried this. But not working

Answer (score 0):

Try simple quote instead of double quotes for the external url, because you're style param already use double quotes :

```
<tr>
  <th> Test table header </th>
    <th style="background: url('external url');" >Column 1 header <br/>How to</th>
 <th style="background: url('external url');" >Column 2 header <br/>How to</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have tried this. not working

Answer (score 0):

Should be working with `background-image: url(external url);` without the quotes:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Q9GFjaY.jpeg);">Column 1 header <br/>How to</th>
    <th style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/xohARva.png);">Column 2 header <br/>How to</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you still don't see it maybe your cells should be bigger

Comment: I have tried this. not working

Comment: I have tried this. not working

Comment: You can run my example it's working, maybe it's a problem with the URL that your using

Comment: Can you provide us the URL that your using